# How does smart tab completion work?

Tags: shell, zsh, autocomplete

If I type this command in zsh:

```
cd foo<TAB>
```

The shell is smart enough to show only *directories* that start with "foo".

Similarly if I type this command in zsh:

```
git commit a<TAB>
```

The shell is smart enough to show only files that start with "a" *and* have uncommitted changes in git.

Where do those smarts come from?

Comment: Please edit your question and specify which shell you are using.

Comment: "How does it work" in not really a good question. What is it, that you don't understand? What have you been reading on this topic so far? Any research done on your own?

Comment: @BulletBob I don't understand the mechanism by which the shell is able to communicate  with arbitrary commands to know what filenames to display for autocompletion.  Is this an API somewhere?

Comment: I would suggest doing some research on your own first in stead of relying on others to do your homework

Comment: @BulletBob That's a frustrating comment.  If I knew where to look for more information on this, then I wouldn't have come _here_.  If I google "tab completion" I can find lots of pages that give _examples_ of tab completion, but I don't know the magic word to search for (if there is one) to find out how it _works under the hood_.

Comment: https://oliverspryn.medium.com/adding-git-completion-to-zsh-60f3b0e7ffbc